# Passing Route.data dynamically thru Router.navigate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I stumble upon the issue of passing values via Router without using the URL param, long story short, the issue was posted here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9804

But as I read thru the thread, it seems that what they end up suggesting is creating a Shared Service which IMHO is a bit overkill.

I want to ask if are there any work around regarding this.

To summarize, I just want to pass the "dynamic" data via

```
Router.navigate(["../somelink", data]);
```

which is used like this:

```
{
    path: 'somelink',
    component: SomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    data: { value: 12345 }
},
```

and being retrieve by this:

```
this.route.data.forEach((data: Data) => {
    this.memberVariable = data["value"]
});
```

Comment: Just use a service.

Comment: Yeah, this is what you and the other talked about in the thread, so they will not support the Router.navigate approach?

Comment: Haven't seen anything that indicates they will.